# Making a custom ButtonStyle in SwiftUI (for MacOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, swiftui

Mine isn't working 100% for some reason. Some modifiers are working and some aren't (noted below). My View struct is like this:

```
    struct MyView: View {

      // ...

          struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
             func makeBody(configuration: CustomButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
                 configuration.label
                     .foregroundColor(Color.white)                      // this works
                     .frame(width: 330, height: 40, alignment: .center) // this doesn't work
                     .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))      // this doesn't work
                     .padding(100)                                      // this works
             }
         }

      // ...

      // in var body...
        Button(action: {
            // ...
        }, label: {
        Text("Confirm")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .background(Color.blue)
        })
        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
```

When I put the ViewModifiers on the Text view in the Button's label, it works fine, but not sure why this doesn't work. TIA!

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, but leaving up here for others. The modifiers weren't in the correct order so it some were just nonexistent. Also I tried applying the custom style to an Image button, but I needed to set the rendering mode to `.template`.